# root finding in R for exponential function

Tags: r, function, mathematical-optimization

I have a function with exponentials :

```
f = function(x){
  exp(3*x)+4*exp(2*x)-3*exp(x)
}
```

this function has one real root which is $\sqrt(7)-2$ or 0.6457513 as discussed [here in Stack Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604573/show-that-a-function-has-exactly-one-real-root/4604766#4604766)

if I try to find the root in R :

```
uniroot(f, lower = -3, upper = 3)$root
[1] -0.4373415
```

the root that R reports me is not the correct one.

Any help why is that happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `uniroot` solution is correct.

We can see this by plotting your function:

```r
f = function(x){
  exp(3*x) + 4*exp(2*x) - 3*exp(x)
}

plot(f, xlim = c(-3, 0))
abline(h = 0, lty = 2)
```

[image]

Note that there is a single root somewhere between -1 and 0. If we draw a vertical line at the uniroot solution, it should coincide with the point where the line crosses the x axis:

```r
abline(v = uniroot(f, lower = -1, upper = 0)$root, lty = 2)
```

[image]

Note that it's easy to confirm whether the value `0.6457513` is a root by passing it to your function. This returns:

```r
f(0.6457513)
#> [1] 15.77041
```

Which tells us this is *not a root*.

If you look at the answer on math overflow, they show that `t = sqrt(7) - 2`, but remember `t` was substituted for `exp(x)`, so `exp(x) = sqrt(7) - 2`, and therefore the root is at `x = log(sqrt(7) - 2)`

```r
log(sqrt(7) - 2)
#> [1] -0.4373408
```

If we feed *this* number into your function we can see that it is indeed a root (within the limits of floating point arithmetic)

```r
f(log(sqrt(7) - 2))
#> [1] 4.440892e-16
```

Comment: how it is correct? it is not the same as the theoretical one !

Comment: `f = function(x){
  (x^2+4*x-3)
}
uniroot(f, lower = 0, upper = 1)$root [1] 0.6457544` this is the same though.!!

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson see my update. The math overflow solution omitted the final step of converting `t` back into `exp(x)`, so the root is `log(sqrt(7) - 2)`, which is what uniroot gives you.